# Dart doesn't recognize type

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the simplified source code, i am fetching dataBaseList from a firebase Database and i know that it only contains Strings:

```
List<String> stringList;
stringList = dataBaseList;
```

It returns this Error: `'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>`

So I thought this solution might fix the problem:

```
List<String> stringList;
stringList = dataBaseList as List<String>;
```

However, it now returns this error:
`type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast`

Is there a solution to this?

I am not that familiar with Stackoverflow conventions so I am sorry if I violated any

Comment: `dataBaseList.cast<String>()`

Comment: You should make that an answer so OP can approve it!